# TouchDelegate with App Widget?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appwidget

Is it possible to use a TouchDelegate with an App Widget, i.e. with RemoteViews? The purpose is to make it easier to tap some buttons on the widget by making the tap area larger, but without making the image take up more space since that will affect the layout.

The TouchDelegate examples I've found requires you to find and use the view IDs in question using `Activity.findViewById()` which I don't think will work through an AppWidgetProvider. If it's not possible, is there any alternative that can achieve the same thing? I have also tried putting the image in a framelayout with padding, but since the padding takes up space this doesn't help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to use a TouchDelegate with an App Widget, i.e. with RemoteViews?

No, sorry.

> I have also tried putting the image in a framelayout with padding, but since the padding takes up space this doesn't help.

Get rid of the padding and assign a `PendingIntent` for the click event of the `FrameLayout`. All subclasses of `View` have click events, even though we tend to focus mostly on `Button` and `ImageButton`. By putting your image inside a container that is sized and positioned where you want touch events to register, and using the same `PendingIntent` for both the image and that container, you can create a larger touch target.

Comment: Thanks, I actually started doing exactly this already! What's weird is that the touch event seems to trigger sporadically when the FrameLayout is tapped, it doesn't execute every time. Any idea what the reason for that could be? The image is not actually inside the FrameLayout, the FrameLayout has been placed over the image within a RelativeLayout. Would that be a problem?

Comment: @mattboy: "Any idea what the reason for that could be?" -- off the top of my head, no. "Would that be a problem?" -- probably not, though you might want to set a background on it briefly to make sure it is sized/positioned where you think it is.